# How to share scope between controller and $mdDialog?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How can I share scope between controller and  $mdDialog (Angular Material)?
I'm using "Controller As" syntax, and I need to use functions of my controller into  $mdDialog cause when it close, I will need some data.
In this code, I need to call "myFunction" in $mdDialog. 
occurs that if I have an object (self.obj) and I need it into 'myFunction', when $mdDialog calls 'myFunction' the object doesn't exists into the scope.

```
angular.module('myApp')
          .controller('myController', myController);

myController.$inject = ['$mdDialog'];

function myController($mdDialog) {

var self = this;
self.obj = {'firstName:'hello','lastName':'world'}


self.myFunction = function () {console.log(JSON.stringfy(self.obj))};

self.showDialog = function (){

    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: function ctrl() {},
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/modal_templates/dialog01.template.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true
    })
}

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use locals option to inject myFunction. Then use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method to create a new function that has its this keyword set to self.

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value

```
self.myFunction = function () {console.log(JSON.stringfy(this.obj))};

$mdDialog.show({
    controller: function ctrl(myfunction) { },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    templateUrl: 'views/modal_templates/dialog01.template.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    locals: {
       myfunctiion: myFunction.bind(self),

   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Awakening Byte, I've edited my question to explain better. My problem is that I need an object inside 'myFunction', and I'wil update this object in a md-button on my modal template.

Comment: updated the answer. You need to use bind() method to lock the context to self

Answer (score 2):

In your controller :

```
.controller('testing',
        function($scope,  $mdDialog) {
 $scope.items = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    $scope.addAddress = function(ev)
    {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: () => this,
              controllerAs: 'ctrl',
              templateUrl: 'views/address.html',
              targetEvent: ev,
              clickOutsideToClose:true,
              locals: {
                  items: $scope.items,
               },
               });
    };
```

**In address.html , access item with 'ctrl'**

```
<din ng-repeat="items in ctrl.items">
{{ items }}
</div>
```

I got this solution from the following link:
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1531